# What is the meaning of triple curly braces {{{ }}} in phtml template files? When and how do we use them?

Tags: magento2, magento2.2, template, phtml

There is a phtml template file in one of the third party Magento 2 extension which has triple **`curly braces {{{ }}}`** in it.
When is this notation used, What does it represent?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Magento uses  option "noEscape" set to true when compiling the template if you want to use {{ }} when {{{ }}} are required to successfully replace the templates.

> /vendor/magento/magento2-base/dev/tests/functional/tests/app/Magento/Customer/Test/Block/Address/Renderer.php

Above is the reference where Magento V 2.2.4 uses **Render output from Address fixture according to data format type using variables.**

- Handlebars HTML-escapes values returned by a `{{expression}}`.
- If you don't want **[Handlebars](https://handlebarsjs.com/guide/#html-escaping)** to escape a value, use the
  "triple-stash", `{{{`.

Comment: Good explanation. +1

Comment: Thanks, Shoaib Munir :)

Answer (score 3):

Handlebars HTML-escapes values returned by a `{{expression}}`. If you don't want Handlebars to escape a value, use the "triple-stash", `{{{`.

```
<div class="entry">
  <h1>{{title}}</h1>
  <div class="body">
    {{{body}}}
  </div>
</div>
```

with this context:

```
{
  title: "All about <p> Tags",
  body: "<p>This is a post about &lt;p&gt; tags</p>"
}
```

results in:

```
<div class="entry">
  <h1>All About &lt;p&gt; Tags</h1>
  <div class="body">
    <p>This is a post about &lt;p&gt; tags</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Reference: https://handlebarsjs.com/guide/#html-escaping